# grails upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3, run-app works but run-war does not

Tags: grails

I am working on someone else's project which was running on Grails 2.2.1, now I intend to upgrade it to 2.3.5, all works fine except when I do 'grails run-war' it throws the following error and an infinitely long stacktrace.

It seems to be attempting to process 'is-tomcat-running'

```
014-06-26 15:07:57,682 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /is-tomcat-running
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:314)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
```

It worked fine with grails 2.2 where the tomcat plugin version was $grailsVersion

I attempted to use tomcat:7.0.50 with 2.3 and this is what happens. Interestingly, 7.0.54 throws a different error.

Comment: I assume you upgraded the plugins? Create a new blank app, and compare buildconfig

Comment: I upgraded the plugins. tomcat 7.0.54 throws a different error because of an internal plugin which is writting in 2.2.1. However, that plugin is being used by an app that runs tomcat:7.0.50 and was upgraded from 2.2.1 to 2.3.5, so I assume that 7.0.50 should work.

Comment: So I went through the old commits, and managed to find the commit that was causing the trouble, but it does not fix the error completely. What it did was change the URLMappings and the main controller behaviour.                                               `  static mappings = {

        "/canvas/$action?/$id?"(controller: 'canvas')
        "/$channel/$game?"(controller:'canvas', action:'play')
   "/"(view:"/index")
         "500"(controller:'Error')
  }`

Comment: The description says "2.3" but isn't more specific than that.  Are you using 2.3.0?

Comment: I was using 2.2.1 upgrading to 2.3.5

Comment: Fixed it, but I cannot post my own response until later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to plugins in if it is `grails 2.3.0` or `2.3.xx`

```
plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.1" 
        //others will be here also but ,change tomcat first
        build ":tomcat:7.0.42"      

    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will fix it. But I came up with a different solution. I used tomcat:7.0.54 and fixed another error regarding grails importing httpbuilder.